# How to get rid of "undefined attribute name" warnings in XHTML5 documents with SVG elements (in Eclipse)?

Tags: html, xml, eclipse, svg, xhtml

I am authoring XHTML5 web pages (i.e. HTML5 as well-formed and valid XML) which contain SVG elements. I am using Eclipse (newest version 2019-12) with Web Tools Platform (WTP) installed, which generally works fine for me, but in this case throws warnings which obviously don't make any sense.

Side note: I am not asking how to include SVG in HTML; there are enough tutorials about that, and my pages behave as expected in browsers. My question relates solely to *Eclipse*, why it shows those warnings, and how to educate it to stop this.

Example XHTML5/SVG document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>XHTML5 SVG test</title>
</head>

<body>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="declaration">
  <symbol id="help" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path fill="var(--fill-color)" d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm1 17h-2v-2h2v2zm2.07-7.75l-.9.92C13.45 12.9 13 13.5 13 15h-2v-.5c0-1.1.45-2.1 1.17-2.83l1.24-1.26c.37-.36.59-.86.59-1.41 0-1.1-.9-2-2-2s-2 .9-2 2H8c0-2.21 1.79-4 4-4s4 1.79 4 4c0 .88-.36 1.68-.93 2.25z"/>
    <circle fill-opacity="0" cursor="pointer" cx="12" cy="12" r="10"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>

<svg class="Icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <use xlink:href="#help"/>
</svg>

</body>

</html>
```

With this document, Eclipse gives a warning for (i.e. underlines) each occurrence of `xmlns`; when hovering the mouse over it, it tells me:

```
Undefined attribute name (xmlns).
```

The same is true for all other occurrences of all attributes in all elements from the `<svg>` namespace.

Furthermore, in the same way, it gives warnings about all elements of the `<svg>` namespace themselves, for example:

```
Unknown tag (symbol).
```

The same is true for all occurrences of all elements from the `<svg>` namespace.

How do I configure Eclipse to make it correctly recognize the page's type and namespaces and parse and validate the page correctly? I'd like to cure the cause, not the symptoms. That is, I would be grateful for solutions which actually make Eclipse recognize types and namespaces, while considering solutions where I have to suppress warnings by using pragmas or filter strings only as a last resort.

Comment: Are you using the editor of [Eclipe WTP](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) or the editor of [Eclipse Wild Web Developer](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper) to open the HTML file?

Comment: Thanks for your time ... I thought it was called "Web Developer Tools" (and hence have used that wrong term). But actually it is indeed called "Web Tools Platform" (WTP).

Comment: What you get with Eclipse Wild Web Developer? If you have both installed, do right-click and _Open With_ to choose which editor you want.

Comment: I just have installed Wild Web Developer (the version it pulled in is 0.7.2.201911151547) and restarted Eclipse. But this didn't help because it did not add any new editor to the *Open With* context menu (thanks for the tip, though). Either I have missed something, or the Wild Web Developer does not work for me. How exactly is the editor you were talking about called in the *Open With* context menu? (Note: I am aware of the last entry in this menu, that is, *Other ...* :-) There is no new editor (compared to the previous installation).)

Comment: O.K. - an hour later I have found out that it is the *Generic Editor* which I should use. However, in that editor there are exactly the same warnings as in the other one (which is *HTML Editor*).

Comment: I guess you're still seeing the persisted warnings of WTP. Do Editing where the warning is to trigger revalidation.

Comment: Thanks again. You are right. After editing and saving, the warnings went away. However, there are much more problems now: For example, I inserted `<ul><li><p>test</p></li></ul>` and some unbalanced `<div>` in the above document, but didn't get any warnings, there is no code completion / content assist etc. Perhaps I missed something - I didn't find where I could configure it. I think I'll continue using the Web Tools Platform and live with those superfluous warnings.

Comment: The HTML Editor in Eclipse WTP, at least, doesn't support SVG. There's also no DTD or Schema created for it to process by looking up the namespace URI in the XML Catalog, either. You'd have to go to the Web/HTML Files/Validation preference page and enter the element and attribute names to ignore. For now.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clear statement and your explanation. Then I'll stop wasting time with that matter and live with the warnings (or disable them).

Comment: @Binarus Please note, all Eclipse projects are open source and are happy to receive contributions. [nitind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60101202/how-to-get-rid-of-undefined-attribute-name-warnings-in-xhtml5-documents-with-s#comment106325289_60101202) is the project lead of Eclipse WTP.

Comment: Thanks for the info which is very interesting to me. While in the past I've tried to contribute to open source projects from time to time, I have to look at Eclipse from the perspective of a user (unfortunately, and for the moment, my time budget does not allow for anything else). So I am glad that @nitind did react to my question and gave such a clear statement; this saved a lot of time, and if anybody could bring a solution to this problem on its way at all, it's probably him.

Comment: I *should* be possible, with some code changes, to let a user associate an `xmlns` value to a URI for use when editing HTML5 (at least where the `html` element explicitly declares its namespace), through the XML Catalog preferences, but I've only seen a SVG 1.1 DTD at http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11-flat-20110816.dtd to try something like that against. And documenting that in a digestible way would certainly be a challenge.

Comment: Thanks again for the tip. This is a little beyond my capabilities (I never have tweaked Eclipse). I went to the XML Catalog (Window -> Preferences -> XML -> XML Catalog) and created a User Specified Entry, using the URL you gave as Location and as Key. As expected, that didn't change anything; the warnings are still there after closing and re-opening the editors. I have noticed that the other DTDs seem to be packed into JAR files, and I have no idea how to do this with that SVG DTD. I'll just live with the situation for the moment ...